# Large black caterpillar, cocoon, moth - Los Angeles

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

This is my first visit here, probably the first of many, since I have many species to identify!

The first is a regular resident of my back yard in the Los Angeles neighborhood of Mt. Washington. It's a large black caterpillar that comes out at night to feed on what I assume is native flora. I have seen as many as five or six at a time in a good (wet) year, but the last couple of years have literally seen only one at a time. Note the ant in the lower left for scale:

[image: Large Black Caterpillar, Los Angeles, CA]

A couple of years ago, I brought one home and kept it in a terrarium until it pupated and hatched.  I have a picture of the cocoon, but can't post more than 2 links right now. It was dark brownish-red, with strands of silk that looked to anchor it to the ground, with the empty body on top.

It turned into this very pretty moth:

[image: Large Black Caterpillar, hatched. Los Angeles]

Unfortunately, it beat up its wings a little, as it took me some time to realize it had hatched. It was released at night.

I had a possible ID at one point on another website, but I didn't follow up with them, and have a lot of trouble searching there for my old thread. Found this place, and thought I'd give it a shot. As I say, I have many more species questions, but I'll just start with this one. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the image of the moth, I think this is a Painted Tiger Moth (*Arachnis picta*). See the image of the moth from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnis_picta) (you can even see the yellow color at the head region):

[image]

An image of the caterpillar can be found [here](http://www.whatsthatbug.com/2013/09/16/painted-arachnis-caterpillar-in-mount-washington/), but this is less decisive.
It also fits with the geographic location where you found the moth, see [here](http://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Arachnis-picta).

Comment: That was fast! Thank you! The location does fit, because that's the same one! Tha'ts the page I couldn't get back to, and couldn't remember the possible species they had mentioned. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Chris - You do realize you used the OP's own photograph as a source, right?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I see different images in the question and my answer.

Comment: @Chris - You linked to [the OP's photograph as a source](http://www.whatsthatbug.com/2013/09/16/painted-arachnis-caterpillar-in-mount-washington/) for your answer. Still, it worked out well for the OP sice he had been searching for it.

Comment: Yes, it did work out well! They are cropped differently, so it wouldn't be immediately apparent that it's the same picture. Thanks again.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Now I got it, strange coincidence.

Comment: @Chris - I did upvote you, btw, regardless. Good answers are good answers.